# Entity Framework row count is always 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my database table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyClass] (
    [Id]       INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Criteria] NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyClass ON;
insert into MyClass(Id, Criteria) values('1', 'Value1');
insert into MyClass(Id, Criteria) values('2', 'Value2');
```

Connection String

```
 <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyTableName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
```

And EFDbContext class

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext {
    public EFDbContext()
        : base("EFDbContext") {
    }

    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}
```

However, the value of 'count' is always zero.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var db = new EFDbContext();            
        var firstValue = db.MyClasses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id > 1);
        var count = db.MyClasses.Count();
        return View();
    }

}
```

**EDIT :** 
I tried var count = db.MyClasses.ToList().Count(); but still returns zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
List<MyClasses> classList = db.MyClasses.ToList();
int count = classList.Count();
```

Comment: please check that your table has the rows.

Comment: I have updated answer. First debug it and check that classList have two rows or not.

Comment: holy crap please don't do this in anything where the size is unbounded. You're getting the entire dataset to call count on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line in your code

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT **SqaCriterion** ON; //It should be **SqlCriterion**
insert into MyClass(Id, Criteria) values('1', 'Value1');
insert into MyClass(Id, Criteria) values('2', 'Value2');
```

Comment: Sorry it just typeo "SET IDENTITY_INSERT **MyClass** ON;" table has 2 rows

Comment: then check in your database..whether it has records

Comment: @SeehyungLee you have set `Id` as `Identity` then how can you insert values in ID column

Comment: I can insert values in the ID column becuase of "SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyClass ON;"